# Expresso Store: Add a custom weight to a Product Modifier

Tags: expresso-store

My client sells Small, Medium, and Large sizes of many products that vary dramatically in weight, and can make a significant difference in shipping cost.

CartThrob Price modifiers allowed me to add columns for things such as "Weight", which I could then pass along as a hidden field when adding the product to the cart. Do Expresso Product Modifiers allow anything similar?

Answer (score 3):

It's not currently possible to set a specific weight to each product variation (modifier option) although it has been requested and in consideration as to the best way to present this as an option.

At present your two options are:

1) To create separate products for each weight variation. This way you can set a handling charge to each one if needed or just set the weight.

2) Create a custom extension using the [extension hooks](https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html) to set the shipping price based on user selection. This could be by way of an adjuster, a handling charge or just additional shipping charges.

The viability of the first one depends on the quantity of products and product variations you have. If it's a small inventory then this may be fine but for larger inventories it may not be ideal.

Comment: For this particular project, almost every product has several variations, each with their own weight, so a unique product for each variation would triple the number of products in the store. Not ideal. As for your 2nd option, wouldn't this still require that we were able to associate a "weight" field with each variation in order to programmatically set the shipping cost? Otherwise where does the weight for each variation come from?

Comment: @cmal Did you solved that issue? I have similar problem with Expresso Store.